# Why an @Output event is in the selector name?

Tags: angular, angular-directive

I have recently encountered this code:

```
@Directive({
    selector: 'mat-autocomplete[optionsScroll]'
})
export class OptionsScrollDirective {  
    @Output('optionsScroll') scroll = new EventEmitter<IAutoCompleteScrollEvent>();
}
```

I know that selectors should be surrounded by brackets, but in this case the selector name is outside of the brackets and instead an `Output` named `optionsScroll` is inside the brackets.

Would someone be kind enough to explain?

Comment: From where did you see this code? I believe this means that the directive can only be used as an attribute directive on a mat-autocomplete component.

Comment: right here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52247691/9369606