# cannot select my ngui-auto-complete scrollbar

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript, autocomplete

[image: gif]

Everytime I select the ngui-auto-complete scrollbar on the dropdown component, the dropdown disappears.

Would it be a better idea to add my scrollbar to another element rather than ngui-auto-complete?

Working example: [**STACKBLITZ**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angu1ar)

**dropdown.component.html**

```
<form [formGroup]="myForm" class="form-style">
  <input
    id="input-dropdown"
    [list-formatter]="autocompleListFormatter"
    type="text"
    class="form-control"
    minlength="3"
    maxlength="20"
    ngui-auto-complete
    formControlName="gridDropdown"
    [source]="dropdownData"
    value-property-name="id"
    display-property-name="name"
    placeholder=" Search"
    [(ngModel)]="value"
    #agInput
  />
</form>
```

[***Source_code***](https://ross2711@bitbucket.org/ross2711/dropdown.git)

Comment: Does https://github.com/ng2-ui/auto-complete/issues/199#issuecomment-303758480 help you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add `[close-on-focusout]="false"` on your input element.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/@ngui/auto-complete

It should look like this.

```
<form [formGroup]="myForm" id="input-dropdown" class="form-style">
  <!-- appAutoFocus - add this to input to use custom auto-focus directive-->
  <input id="input-dropdown" [list-formatter]="autocompleListFormatter" type="text" class="form-control"
    minlength="3" maxlength="20" ngui-auto-complete formControlName="gridDropdown" [source]="dropdownData" [close-on-focusout]="false"
    value-property-name="id" display-property-name="name" placeholder=" Search" [(ngModel)]="value" #agInput />
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you can rely on others do implement basic functionality for you, Material Design components for Angular might be something helpful. It has also an autocomplete dropdown component https://material.angular.io/components/autocomplete/overview

I have not tested that with large scrollbars, bar I found [Infinite scroll for autocomplete in Angular Material 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51293949/infinite-scroll-for-autocomplete-in-angular-material-6) which looks promising, i.e. that scrollbars seem to work as they should.